# Node.js datatables editor - How to use a (knex) VIEW that composes a join

Tags: javascript, node.js, datatables, knex.js

I'm using the node.js datatable editor library. When trying to do a complex left join 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin AND (securities.mic = portfolios_isin_mm.mic)' ... like this:

```
let editor = new Editor( db, 'portfolios_isin_mm' )
    .fields(
        new Field( 'portfolios_isin_mm.account_id' ),
        new Field( 'portfolios_isin_mm.user_id' ),
        new Field( 'portfolios_isin_mm.uid_foreign' )
        new Field( 'securities.issuer_name' ),
        new Field( 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin' ),
        new Field( 'portfolios_isin_mm.mic' ),
       )

    .leftJoin( 'portfolios_isin', 'portfolios_isin.id', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.uid_foreign' )
    .leftJoin( 'securities', 'securities.isin', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin AND (securities.mic = portfolios_isin_mm.mic)' );
    //.leftJoin( 'securities', 'securities.isin', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin' );
```

I'm getting an error. Debugging the error shows me:

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`mic)`' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Connection.query (/home/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
    at /home/myproject/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:152:18
    at Promise._execute (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:313:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
    at Client_MySQL._query (/home/myproject/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:146:12)
    at Client_MySQL.query (/home/myproject/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:197:17)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/home/myproject/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:146:36)
    at Runner.tryCatcher (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Runner.query (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:15:34)
    at /home/myproject/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:65:21
    at tryCatcher (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at /home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:185:26
    at tryCatcher (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/myproject/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'.`mic)`\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'select count(`portfolios_isin_mm`.`id`) as `cnt` from `portfolios_isin_mm` left join `portfolios_isin` on `portfolios_isin`.`id` = `portfolios_isin_mm`.`uid_foreign` left join `securities` on `securities`.`isin` = `portfolios_isin_mm`.`isin AND (securities`.`mic = portfolios_isin_mm`.`mic)`' }
```

... with the php libraries it was working just fine:

```
->leftJoin( 'securities', 'securities.isin', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin AND (securities.mic = portfolios_isin_mm.mic)' )
```

Supposedly I can quote 'The only way to do this at the moment is to create a VIEW that composes that join then you can select from that view. The readTable ([https://editor.datatables.net/docs/1.8.1/nodejs/classes/*editor*.editor.html#readtable](https://editor.datatables.net/docs/1.8.1/nodejs/classes/_editor_.editor.html#readtable)) method can be used to read information from the view while still updating to the host table.'

How can I get the complex left join to work in node.js as well (using a VIEW that composes that join (using knex))?

... I'm using $ node -v ... v10.15.0 and "datatables.net-editor-server": "^1.8.1"

Comment: This ought to work fine. But what I noticed was that there are some syntax errors in the generated sql query:

Comment: Yes. But how to solve it to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the last leftjoin.

```
.leftJoin( 'securities', 'securities.isin', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin AND (securities.mic = portfolios_isin_mm.mic)' )
```

This is why a wrong SQL query was generated:

```
select count(`portfolios_isin_mm`.`id`) as `cnt` from `portfolios_isin_mm` left join `portfolios_isin` on `portfolios_isin`.`id` = `portfolios_isin_mm`.`uid_foreign` left join `securities` on `securities`.`isin` = `portfolios_isin_mm`.`isin AND (securities`.`mic = portfolios_isin_mm`.`mic)`'
```

Notice the incomplete quotes starting from: `portfolios_isin_mm`.`isin

You should consider using andOn() to include the 'AND' in your query:

```
.leftJoin('securities', function() {
        this.on('securities.isin', '=', 'portfolios_isin_mm.isin')
            .andOn('securities.mic', '=', portfolios_isin_mm.mic')
    })
```